# Disable APC Cache for cached files?

Tags: php, opcode

I have a quite large website, in which there is a forum powered by phpBB. I have APC enabled with 1Gb of RAM. **phpBB generates a lot of php files of cache** (60 000-70 000 in my case), and they rapidly **fill up APC memory**. I was thinking to disable apc caching of such files through the apc.filter option. In your opinion, does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Playing with the filters option definitely makes sense. I would try that first.

Otherwise, you can set `apc.ttl` to clean out the opcode cache entries after a set amount of time. It's set in seconds; try something like 3600 to start and adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to turn off filesystem caching in phpBB.
Your solution makes sense too.

Comment: But I don't want to turn off phpBB filesystem caching...

Comment: Hmm, it looks like phpBB template system can't use SQL or in-memory caching, so caching on filesystem is the only option. You are right, it's better not to turn it off.